# How do I insert this custom data type with libpq?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpq, composite-types

I'm having some difficulty with inserting some data using libpq. I have two custom data types:

```
create type size as (width real, height real);
create type rotated_rect as (angle real, center point, bounding_box box, size size)
```

and I would like to insert a record into a table which has a rotated_rect field, so for the field using libpq I'm putting together the string value:

```
paramv[3] = "(10.5,10.1,10.2,20,20,20,40,(5,5))";
```

However, it's giving me the error: invalid input syntax for type point: "10.1"

I've also tried:

```
paramv[3] = "(10.5,(10.1,10.2),20,20,20,40,(5,5))"; -> invalid input syntax for "(10.1"
paramv[3] = "(10.5,(10.1,10.2),(20,20,20,40),(5,5))"; -> as above
```

and the sql command I'm using is:

```
res = PQexecParams(conn, "insert into test (r,b,s,rr) values ($1::real,$2::box,$3::size,$4::rotated_rect)", 4, NULL, paramv, NULL, NULL,0);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You error message is incomplete and misleading. The actual error message should be `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type point: "(10.1"`. Please, *always* provide the verbatim error message.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter where is it misleading? That's exactly what I've put!

Comment: It is not. Read again, and please fix your question. Also, your added `INSERT` statement has more values than parameters.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter 4 values, 4 parameters

Comment: Yeah, but how to do it in **binary** mode, instead of **ascii** mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What got me were that escaped double quotes and parenthesis need to be used around the values representing a field of the custom compound data type which requires more than one value to create, so:

```
paramv[0] = "(10.5,\"(10.1,10.2)\",\"(20,20,20,40)\",\"(5,5)\")";
```

As this string is used as a parameter, the single quotes that would usually wrap the outer parenthesis are not needed.

In a non-parameterised query, it would be implemented like so with the single quotes:

```
res = PQexec(conn, "insert into test (rr) values ('(10.5,\"(10.1,10.2)\",\"(20,20,20,40)\",\"(5,5)\")')");
```

Answer (score 2):

This works (tested in Postgres 9.3):

```
SELECT '(10.5,"(10.1,10.2)","(20,20,20,40)","(5,5)")'::rotated_rect
```

Returns:

```
'(10.5,"(10.1,10.2)","(20,40),(20,20)","(5,5)")'
```

Note the different syntax for `box`. Try this form.

Comment: I'm inserting, not selecting, and no, `paramv[3] = "(10.5,\"(10.1,10.2)\",\"(20,20,20,40)\",\"(5,5)\")"` doesn't work, giving the error: malformed record literal "(20,20,20,40)" detail: too many columns

Comment: I works, I tested in Postgrs 9.3 before posting. But try the syntax Postgres returns.

Comment: doesn't work with libpq: `paramv[3] = "(10.5,\"(10.1,10.2),\"(20,21),(22,40)\",\"(5,5)\")";` gives the error: "malformed record literal: "(20,21),(22,40)" detail: junk after right parenthesis