# Preparing a placeholder statement for binding

Tags: c, postgresql

I have created a table as

```
CREATE TABLE customerobj (
    custno numeric,
    addr address_object  
);
```

and a composite-type as

```
CREATE TYPE address_object AS (
    state char(2),
    zip char(10)
);
```

I want to create a single placeholder statement for the inserting values into the `customerobj` table in  a C program.

I have a statement as

```
"INSERT INTO customerobj(custno,addr) VALUES (:custno,:adrr);"
```

stored in a text constant pointer. When I do a piecewise bind, it works for the `custno` but fails for the composite-type, `addr`.

Error: `Invalid datatype`.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192830/how-do-i-insert-this-custom-data-type-with-libpq